# How to extract links from a website in python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to webscrape the below website. As a first step, I would like to get the links from which to extract the text. However, when I do the following, I get an empty list:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm'
r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, features = "lxml")

r.select('.itemTitle')
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Those `.itemTitle` are inserted using JS, so bs4 can't see them. You'll need a tool like selenium.

Comment: got it, I will need to switch to selenium then, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `pandas` approach:

```py
import json
import string

import requests

url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json"
speeches = json.loads(
    "".join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, requests.get(url).text))
)
for speech in speeches:
    try:
        print(f"https://www.federalreserve.gov{speech['l']}")
    except KeyError:
        print("No link :(")
```

Output:

```
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/barr20230329a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/jefferson20230327a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bowman20230314a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/barr20230309a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bowman20230303a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/waller20230302a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/jefferson20230227a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/jefferson20230224a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/cook20230216a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bowman20230215a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bowman20230213a.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/waller20230210a.htm

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also request the JSON from the enpoint data is loaded from and based on your imports convert it into a pandas dataframe.

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd 


pd.DataFrame(
    json.loads(requests.get(f'https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json').content)
)
```

###### Output

|  | d | t | s | lo | l | a | o | v | video | updateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3/29/2023 8:30:00 AM | Brief Remarks | Vice Chair for Supervision Michael S. Barr | At the National Community Reinvestment Coalition Just Economy Conference, Washington, D.C. (via prerecorded video) | /newsevents/speech/barr20230329a.htm |  | no |  | No | nan |
| 1 | 3/27/2023 5:00:00 PM | Implementation and Transmission of Monetary Policy | Governor Philip N. Jefferson | At the H. Parker Willis Lecture, Washington and Lee University, Lexington, Virginia | /newsevents/speech/jefferson20230327a.htm |  | no |  | No | nan |
| 2 | 3/14/2023 5:20:00 PM | The Innovation Imperative: Modernizing Traditional Banking | Governor Michelle W. Bowman | At the Independent Community Bankers of America ICBA Live 2023 Conference, Honolulu, Hawaii | /newsevents/speech/bowman20230314a.htm |  | no |  | No | nan |
| 3 | 3/9/2023 10:00:00 AM | Supporting Innovation with Guardrails: The Federal Reserve’s Approach to Supervision and Regulation of Banks’ Crypto-related Activities | Vice Chair for Supervision Michael S. Barr | At the Peterson Institute for International Economics, Washington, D.C. | /newsevents/speech/barr20230309a.htm |  | no | https://www.youtube.com/user/PetersonInstitute | No | nan |
| 4 | 3/3/2023 3:00:00 PM | Panel on “Design Issues for Central Bank Facilities in the Future” | Governor Michelle W. Bowman | At The Chicago Booth Initiative on Global Markets Workshop on Market Dysfunction, Chicago, Illinois | /newsevents/speech/bowman20230303a.htm |  | no |  | No | nan |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 973 | 1/18/2017 3:00:00 PM | The Goals of Monetary Policy and How We Pursue Them | Chair Janet L. Yellen | At the Commonwealth Club, San Francisco, California | /newsevents/speech/yellen20170118a.htm |  | no |  | Yes | nan |
| 974 | 1/17/2017 10:00:00 AM | Monetary Policy in a Time of Uncertainty | Governor Lael Brainard | At the Brookings Institution, Washington, D.C. | /newsevents/speech/brainard20170117a.htm |  | no |  | Yes | nan |
| 975 | 1/12/2017 7:00:00 PM | Welcoming Remarks | Chair Janet L. Yellen | At the Conversation with the Chair: A Teacher Town Hall Meeting, Washington, D.C. | /newsevents/speech/yellen20170112a.htm |  | no |  | Yes | nan |
| 976 | 1/7/2017 11:15:00 AM | Low Interest Rates and the Financial System | Governor Jerome H. Powell | At the 77th Annual Meeting of the American Finance Association, Chicago, Illinois | /newsevents/speech/powell20170107a.htm |  | no |  | No | nan |